# Jenkins pipeline docker.image call generates a timeout

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I recently upgraded my jenkins/Docker installation and since, I randomly experience timeout when i run a docker in my jenkins pipeline scripts, in which I start a docker like:

```
docker.image("${dockerImage}").inside(' -v /opt/software/:/software/:Z'){
 .....
}
```

This occurs randomly and my job crash with the following error message ( see extended log at the bottom of this thread):

```
ERROR: Timeout after 10 seconds
```

**UPDATE:**
My pipeline script:

```
stage('Build'){
    node("master"){
    withEnv(['GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true']){ 
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "$myGitSHA"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId:"${myGitCredentialsId}" , url:"${myGitUrl}" ]]])
        }

        docker.image("${dockerImage}").inside(' -v /opt/software/:/software/:Z'){
            // Cleaning any the previous build
            sh "make all"
        } // docker               
    } // node
} // stage
```

I wonder whether there is an option to increase the default timeout value set currently to 10s.

thanks

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 995:993 -v /opt/software/:/software/:Z -w /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/RegressionTests/jobs/rg_centos5-x86_64-gcc-4.1.2/workspace 
-v /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/RegressionTests/jobs/rg_centos5-x86_64-gcc-4.1.2/workspace:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/RegressionTests/jobs/rg_centos5-x86_64-gcc-4.1.2/workspace:rw 
-v /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/RegressionTests/jobs/rg_centos5-x86_64-gcc-4.1.2/workspace@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/RegressionTests/jobs/rg_centos5-x86_64-gcc-4.1.2/workspace@tmp:rw 
-e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** 
-e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** --entrypoint cat centos5_labs_ompi14
ERROR: Timeout after 10 seconds

java.io.IOException: Failed to run image 'centos5_labs_ompi14'. Error: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.client.DockerClient.run(DockerClient.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.WithContainerStep$Execution.start(WithContainerStep.java:178)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:128)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.node(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker$Image.inside(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/docker-workflow/WEB-INF/lib/docker-workflow.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy:116)
    at Script1.extMain(Script1.groovy:305)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor349.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:328)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: could you please post your whole pipeline script?

Comment: I just put the pipeline script. It basically crashes after a timeout of 10s which seems to be  hardcoded in the DockerClient.java (https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/client/DockerClient.java#L268)

Comment: Can you include the whole error message as well, rather than just the top three lines?

Comment: I believe the timeout value should be parameterisable. This feature was implemented in the latest DockerClient.java

https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-workflow

if I revert back to release 1.9 it seems to work fine.

Comment: See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42322 and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42667

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the issue is due to the hardcoded 10s timeout value, as one can read it from this link;
[docker workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/client/DockerClient.java#L268)
https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/client/DockerClient.java#L268

In some cases this is far too short. A solution would be to have this timeout value as a parameter which is set by the user.

Comment: How ? Any sample snippet? coz `--stop-timeout = 600` doesn't work in my case

Answer (score 0):

I also run into the same problem since yesterday. my docker pipeline version is 1.10.

The issue happens when it try to initiate the docker container from the fol

```
def abcd_image = docker.image('172.16.181.203:5000/abcd:1.0.0.7')
        abcd_image.inside("--privileged -u root -v ${actual_workspace}:${chroot}/code") {
```

I tried ssh into the docker host and restart docker service. After that, it works but the issue comes back after couple hours.

Comment: In my case moving back to the previous version of the docker plugin was the solution I came to until the current issue is fixed.

Comment: Same. I reverted to 1.0.9 and it's good. There's another Jenkins machine that I was running 1.10 and run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen this error recently on a random run.

I am using the Jenkins version 2.375.2 and Docker plugin 1.2.10

I would recommend to upgrade to the newer version (currently 1.3.2).

Answer (score -1):

You can manually set the timeout limit using the "timeout" option.

Set a timeout period for the Pipeline run, after which Jenkins should abort the Pipeline. For example:

`options { timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') }`

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit